# Escape JavaScript encoded strings in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am receiving a snippet of javascript from a POST request. Here is (part) as an example

```
iCart.updateBlock($$('div.cart', 'div.layout-1column'), "<div class=\"cart\">\n\n    <div class=\"page-title title-buttons\">\n        <h1>Basket<\/h1>\n
```

I can probably strip the javascript using basic php string manipulation if the javascript code is consistent between calls. So then I am left with the javascript encoded string

```
<div class=\"cart\">\n\n    <div class=\"page-title title-buttons\">\n        <h1>Basket<\/h1>\n
```

I basically want to do what this [site](https://www.freeformatter.com/javascript-escape.html#ad-output) explains in reverse

- Horizontal Tab is replaced with \t
- Vertical Tab is replaced with \v
- Nul char is replaced with \0
- Backspace is replaced with \b
- Form feed is replaced with \f
- Newline is replaced with \n
- Carriage return is replaced with \r
- Single quote is replaced with \'
- Double quote is replaced with \"
- Backslash is replaced with \

Is there a PHP function that does this? I don't particularly want to write a parser to do this. Result being

```
<div class="cart"><div class="page-title title-buttons"><h1>Basket<\/h1>
```

I can only provide a small snippet of the returned javascript. When the full string is run through the site linked, the HTML that is un-escaped is complete and valid.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe json_encode() will do what you need. It will, however, append and prepend quotes as it is making a JSON string value.

Answer (score 0):

For my purposes, this was good enough

```
$html = strtr($html, [
    "\t"    => '',
    "\v"    => '',
    "\n"    => '',
    "\\\\"  => "\\",
    "\\\""  => "\"",
    "\'"    => "'",
    "\r"    => '',
    "\b"    => '',
    "\f"    => '',
    "\/"    => '/',
]);
```